# Remove sub string from a column's text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've the following two columns in Postgres table

```
name | last_name
----------------
AA   | AA aa
BBB  | BBB bbbb
.... | ..... 
.... | .....
```

How can I update the `last_name` by removing `name` text from it?

final out put should be like

```
name | last_name
----------------
AA   | aa
BBB  | bbbb
.... | ..... 
.... | .....
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET last_name = regexp_replace(last_name, '^' || name || ' ', '');
```

This only removes one copy from the beginning of the column and correctly removes the trailing space.

**Edit**

I'm using a regular expression here. `'^' || name || ' '` builds the regular expression, so with the 'Davis McDavis' example, it builds the regular expression `'^Davis '`. The `^` causes the regular expression to be anchored to the beginning of the string, so it's going to match the word 'Davis' followed by a space *only at the beginning* of the string it is replacing in, which is the `last_name` column.

You could achieve the same effect without regular expressions like this:

```
UPDATE table SET last_name = substr(last_name, length(name) + 2);
```

You need to add two to the length to create the offset because substr is one-based (+1) and you want to include the space (+1). However, I prefer the regular expression solution even though it probably performs worse because I find it somewhat more self-documenting. It has the additional advantage that it is idempotent: if you run it again on the database it won't have any effect. The `substr/offset` method is not idempotent; if you run it again, it will eat more characters off your last name.

Comment: What about the spaces between the words?

Comment: Yeah, that's the trailing space I handle by adding `|| ' '` to the end. Do you have other whitespace issues than what one would infer from your question?

Comment: @Daniel Lyons: Could you please explain how your regexp works? thanks

Comment: @Daniel Lyons A little explanation would be appreciated, like how it handles `Davis McDavis`

Answer (score 13):

Not sure about syntax, but try this:

```
UPDATE table   
SET last_name = TRIM(REPLACE(last_name,name,''))
```

I suggest first to check it by selecting  :

```
 SELECT REPLACE(last_name,name,'')  FROM  table
```

Comment: Close, but two problems: not handling spaces or if the firstname occurs in the lastname. E.g., if my name were Davis McDavis, his original text would be `'Davis McDavis'` and you'd change it to `' Mc'`.

Comment: What about the spaces between the words?

Comment: @Mithun: Added TRIM to handle spaces. Daniel's problem remain

Answer (score 6):

you need the replace function see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html

```
UPDATE table SET last_name = REPLACE(last_name,name,'')
```

Comment: What about the spaces between the words?

Comment: you can use:  trim(both ' ' from REPLACE(last_name,name,''))